# Qt Assistant -SetSource -ShowUrl

Tags: c++, qt

The problem that I am facing at the moment is that when I want to start the Qt Assistant programmatic it won't show me the right Page. I always have to hit the enter button in the assistant in order to load the page I want.

Here is the code I used for starting the Qt Assistant.

```
static QProcess a_assistantProcess;
   bool a_isAssistantProcessRunning = a_assistantProcess.isOpen();
   if (  !a_isAssistantProcessRunning )
   {  
      QStringList a_args;
      a_args << "-collectionFile";
      a_args << S_HELPFILE_PATH;
      a_args << "-enableRemoteControl";
      a_args << "-showUrl";
      a_args << "qthelp://ch.mcs.autoqtassistentdocus/doc/Calculate_Manual_de.html#batchbetrieb";
      QFile a_assistantExe( S_ASSISTANT_PATH );
      if ( a_assistantExe.exists() )
      {
         a_assistantProcess.start( S_ASSISTANT_PATH, a_args );
         a_assistantProcess.waitForStarted();
   }
```

I also tried to send the command per stdin as mentioned in the documentation.
[Using Qt Assistant Remotely](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/assistant-custom-help-viewer.html#using-qt-assistant-remotely)

```
QByteArray a_array;
         QString a_keyword = getKeyWordFromContextID( t_contextID );
         a_array.append( "SetSource qthelp://ch.mcs.autoqtassistentdocus/doc/Calculate_Manual_de.html#batchbetrieb" );
         a_assistantProcess.write( a_array + "\n" );
```

I am very confused since the documentation tells you the following about the SetSource command:

> Displays the given . 
>   The URL can be absolute or relative to the
>   currently displayed page. If the URL is absolute, it has to be a valid
>   Qt help system URL. That is, starting with "qthelp://".

Any help woud be very appriciatied